# Angular/2 NG/2 : ngModel - bind to a property that does not yet exist

Tags: angular

I am dynamically creating a form based on an observable being passed into my child component using "| async". Using the observable I create an object property which I bind form elements to using [ngModel]= however, the form is rendering before the property is ready and it bombs out because I am trying to bind to an element that does not exist. For example;

```
<ng-select
    [options]="options"
    placeholder="Select one"
    multiple="true"
    [ngModel]="chosenAssets[asset.id]"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
>
</ng-select>
```

Where chosenAssets[asset.id] does not yet exist. I'm struggling to get it to work using the Elvis operator. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest displaying the `<ng-select>` as soon `chosenAssets[asset.id]` does exist, e.g. using `*ngIf`

`<ng-select
    *ngIf="chosenAssets[asset.id]"
    [options]="options"
    placeholder="Select one"
    multiple="true"
    [ngModel]="chosenAssets[asset.id]"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
>
</ng-select>`

hope this helps :-)